# BiMap single function to convert values to concatenated string value?

Tags: java, dictionary, bimap

Is there something equivalent to get all keys (or inverses) from a bit map and concat each with a special character as a completely new string (without iterating through the map and building it manually?

```
private static final BiMap<String, String> stuff = HashBiMap.create();
static {
    stuff.put("S1", "STUFF_TYPE_1");
    stuff.put("S2", "STUFF_TYPE_2");
    stuff.put("S3", "STUFF_TYPE_3");
} 

// The non-terminal <> is what I'm asking if something like exists either with bimap or some other container?
private static final String concateKeys = <stuff.getAllKeys().assignDelimiter("|").toString();>
```

Then the Value for concateKeys = "S1|S2|S3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a Guava `BiMap`, this is just

```
Joiner.on('|').join(stuff.keySet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at the `Joiner` class of the [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained).